# Connecting to exchange with php - 403

Tags: php, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get calendars from exchange. But exchange return 403 http code

```
$action='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/FindItem';
    $headers = array(
        'Method: POST',
        'Connection: Keep-Alive',
        'User-Agent: PHP-SOAP-CURL',
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        'SOAPAction: "'.$action.'"',
    );
    $ch = curl_init('https://www.outlook.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx');
$request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns1:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007"/></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:FindItem Traversal="Shallow"><ns2:ItemShape><ns1:BaseShape>Default</ns1:BaseShape></ns2:ItemShape><ns2:CalendarView StartDate="2012-06-12T15:18:34+03:00" EndDate="2014-06-12T15:18:34+03:00"/><ns2:ParentFolderIds><ns1:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar"/></ns2:ParentFolderIds></ns2:FindItem></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_NTLM);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$password); //$user and $password are ok
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
    $i = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($i);
```

This code gives me:

```
string(0) ""
Array
(
[url] => https://www.outlook.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 403
[header_size] => 746
[request_size] => 2021
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 1
[total_time] => 2.849341
[namelookup_time] => 3.8E-5
[connect_time] => 4.1E-5
[pretransfer_time] => 0.000162
[size_upload] => 693
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 243
[download_content_length] => 0
[upload_content_length] => 693
[starttransfer_time] => 2.663647
[redirect_time] => 0.18565
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => ......
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => .....
[local_port] => 42052
```

)

When i set bad user or password, then exchange gives me 401. When user and password are ok, exchange gives me 403. Where is problem?

Comment: `A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action`

Comment: Status code 403 responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access, for some reason, to the requested resource by the client.

Comment: Make sure your `curl` has `CURLAUTH_NTLM` package.

Comment: @user876345 my curl has NTLM package.

Comment: @DainisAbols I dont understand your answer. Forgive me, my english is not so good. So what have I to do to get this calendars from exchange?

Comment: Can you access the ASMX page from your browser? Can you access the WSDL page from your browser?

Comment: Yes and Yes. I can also get  WSDL with my code with curl in php - wsdl i getting fine

Comment: Now i have: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC | CURLAUTH_NTLM);` and 403 When i change it to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);` i have 401, but my $user and $password are correct... Maybe this is some kind of clue, but not for me :/